# Rolling over 7 Calendar date from each given current date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count, rolling-computation

**Given:**

```
calendar_date Date_Key  RowN 
03-OCT-21     20211003  1
03-OCT-21     20211003  2
03-OCT-21     20211003  3
04-OCT-21     20211004  4
07-OCT-21     20211007  5
07-OCT-21     20211007  6
09-OCT-21     20211009  7
10-OCT-21     20211010  8
13-OCT-21     20211013  9
13-OCT-21     20211013  10
13-OCT-21     20211013  11
15-OCT-21     20211015  12
17-OCT-21     20211017  13
```

Needed: Rolling over 7 Calender date from each given current date

This is my code which is not giving me proper result

```
select z.calendar_date,z.date_key,ceil(z.rown/7) as Grp from
(select b.calendar_date,b.date_key ,rownum as RowN
from Samp.cal_date_dim a, Samp.cal_date_dim b
where b.date_key-a.date_key>0 and b.date_key-a.date_key<=6)z
```

Code Selection Explain: If It's start from 03 OCT, then 03 OCT - 09 OCT -> Group 1. If It's start from 04 OCT, then 04 OCT - 10 OCT -> Group 2.

OutPut Required or Desired Result

```
calendar_date  Grp  
03-OCT-21      1    
03-OCT-21      1    
03-OCT-21      1    
04-OCT-21      1    
07-OCT-21      1  
07-OCT-21      1  
09-OCT-21      1

04-OCT-21      2    
07-OCT-21      2  
07-OCT-21      2  
09-OCT-21      2
10-OCT-21      2

07-OCT-21      3
07-OCT-21      3
09-OCT-21      3
10-OCT-21      3
13-OCT-21      3
13-OCT-21      3
13-OCT-21      3
```

Comment: Rolling 7-day WHAT?  Usually, there would be some aggregation function, such as `MAX()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()` or `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking for a self-join, along with `dense_rank()`:

```
select dd.*, cd.seqnum as grp
from (select calendar_date, Date_Key,
             dense_rank() over (order by calendar_date) as seqnum
      from Samp.cal_date_dim
      group by calendar_date, Date_Key
     ) cd join
     Samp.cal_date_dim dd
     on dd.calendar_date >= cd.calendar_date and
        dd.calendar_date < cd.calendar_date + interval '7' day;
```

Comment: I think single quotes are misplaced. It should be `cd.calendar_date + interval '7' day`